# Iterate over a Hash map of Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have `csv` file that contains data, and I want to parse all data separated by comma, I have done the code for reading data from the file.

How am I going to llop through the data?

Here is my code:

```
    ArrayList<String> keys;             // Holds key names from header row
    ArrayList<String> values;           // Holds the values read from subsequent rows

    HashMap<String, String> row;        // Holds the key/value pairs for each data row

    String line, header;


    ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>(); // Create ArrayList to hold HashMaps for all rows

    try {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("myfile.csv"), "UTF-8");

        /* Get list of keys from the header row; split into an ArrayList */

        header = in.nextLine();
        keys = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(header.split(",")));

        /* Read and process every subsequent row (record) in CSV file */

        while ( in.hasNextLine() ) {

            /* Get next line */

            line = in.nextLine();

            /* Create new map for current row */

            row = new HashMap<>();

            /* Split comma-separated values into ArrayList */

            values = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));

            /* Populate map, using key names from the header row */

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {

                row.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));

            }

            /* Add map to data container */

            data.add(row);

        }

         in.close();

          // HERE I want to loop through data and display all key values
          // How am I going to do it?
          // the csv contains columns: firstname lastname city address
         }

    catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println(e.toString());

    }
```

Can any one help how to loop through the data ?

Comment: Can you please give an example line of your csv and what output you are expecting?

Comment: @NicholasK FirstName,MiddleInitial,LastName,StreetAddress,City,State,ZipCode
Martha,C,Zermeno,928 Arrowood Drive,Jacksonville,FL,32217

Comment: @NicholasK Thanks

Comment: @NicholasK I want to show data in like this:
Martha C Zermeno (\n)
928 Arrowood Drive (\n)
Jacksonville, FL 32217 (\n)

Comment: You'll need to add all these things in the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , change your Arraylist type to avoid casting all time. That means do it like this your `data ArrayList`;

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then add your printing area to this `Stream` code.I added comment to understand clearly.

```
//loop on data list
data.forEach(hashMapOfRows -> {
    //seperate all data to read carefully,you can modify to your wants
    System.out.println("------------------");
    //for iteratable element is hashmap. So iterate on key value pair and print
    hashMapOfRows.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.print(key + ":" + value + ","));
    //seperate between elements.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------------");
});
```